# Jordan 125T fuse box

Tags: electrical, fuse, scooter

I have a Jordan 125T scooter and can't find the fuse box anywhere. I've looked all over the scooter and tried searching on the Internet.

Any ideas about how to find it?

Comment: I don't know where you fuse box is at, but there is a [Hayne's Manual](http://www.wemoto.com/bikes/chinese_motorcycle/qingqi_qm_125_t_scooter_125cc/04-09/picture/manual_haynes/) available for it.